# Strip URL to get YouTube ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, youtube

I have:

```
var post = $('.post');
post.find('.video embed').each(function(){
    v = $(this);
    youtubeID = v.attr('src').replace(/^.*youtube.com.*(?:\/|v=)(\w+)\//g,"");
    console.log(youtubeID);
})
```

Here's an example URL taken from the embed src

`http://www.youtube.com/v/_eeZnLX_XBM&rel=0&egm=0&showinfo=0&fs=1`

It strips the everything up to `/v/` but not the ampersand and everything after that.

I want `_eeZnLX_XBM` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
youtubeID = v.attr('src').match(/youtube\.com.*?v[\/=](\w+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

so just add another replace for the rest:

```
var post = $('.post');
post.find('.video embed').each(function(){
    v = $(this);
    youtubeID = v.attr('src').replace(/^.*youtube.com.*(?:\/|v=)(\w+)\//g,"").replace(/&.*/g, "");
    console.log(youtubeID);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = v.attr('src');
youtubeID = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 ,url.indexOf('&'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.post').find('.video embed').each(function(){
    youtubeID = $(this).attr('src').match(/\/([^&/]+)&/)[1];

    console.log(youtubeID);
})
```

[visualization of the regex](http://strfriend.com/vis?re=%5C%2F%28%5B%5E%26%2F%5D%2B%29%26)